# How do I sort two lists of different objects based on the int values in the objects of the second list?

Tags: java

I'm making a network call that gives me a list of `CoinPriceQueryResult` objects:

```
public class CoinPriceQueryResult {
    private String coinQueryId;
    private double price;
}
```

How can I sort this list into the order of my second list of objects:

```
public class CoinStatus {
    private String coinQueryId;
    private int position;
}
```

based on the `position`.

```
List<CoinQueryResult> listQueryResult = new ArrayList();
listQueryResult.add("penny", 1.15);
listQueryResult.add("nickel", 5.05);
listQueryResult.add("dime", 10.10);

List<CoinStatus> listCoinStatus = new ArrayList();
listCoinStatus.add("nickel", 0);
listCoinStatus.add("penny", 1);
listCoinStatus.add("dime", 2);
```

I want `listQueryResult` to be sorted in the order of

nickel, penny, dime

How do I get the sorted list using the  int value `position`in the `CoinStatus` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a `Map` that maps each coin name to its position/priority. Then, use [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) to sort based on that `Map`.

```java
Map<String, Integer> position = listCoinStatus.stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(CoinStatus::getCoinQueryId, CoinStatus::getPosition));
listQueryResult.sort(Comparator.comparing(r -> position.get(r.getCoinQueryId())));
```

Comment: Demo here: https://ideone.com/tKlMDY